# Running CakePHP app on subdomain/subfolder (all else failed)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, subdomain, subdirectory

First of all, I did search and search the web for solutions to my problem, but none of the found answers worked for me.

So, here I am, asking for help (yet again) in configuring CakePHP 1.3 to run on a subdomain/subfolder.

Here are the details:

I have an app built on CakePHP 1.3 that works like clockwork in the root folder. All loads well, all routes work well.

I need to install this app on a machine to wich I have no root access, only to a subfolder that has a subdomain set up for it + database access for the app.

I have tried all .htaccess configurations that I found on the web, and the best result was that the PHP part of the app was processing data and accessing the database. However, none of the webroot files were loading (no CSS, no JS, no nothing).

I have tried [this](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/cguyer/2009/10/18/mod-rewrite-on-godaddy-shared-hosting), [this](http://www.solutions4all.info/post/cakephp-allow-sub-directory-by-htaccess), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947396/set-up-cakephp-in-a-subdirectory-wordpress-is-installed-in-the-root) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712150/htaccess-for-cakephp-and-joomla-in-subfolder-subdomain) and a whole bunch of other solutions, but none provided a working solution for my case.

1. the server setup for the httpd.conf is out of my reach
2. the www_root/.htaccess file is currently empty
3. my cakephp subfolder/subdomain is named 'test'
4. the cakephp .htaccess files are:

a. test/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

b. test/app/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
```

c. test/app/webroot/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I reverted to the default settings, as no other settings worked as needed.

Comment: Using mod_rewriting has been configured properly just unarchiving the cakephp archive in <document_root>/test should have everything working for you at http::/domain.com/test.

Couple of common causes of mod_rewrite not properly configured are:

- "Allowoverride all" not set for your document root in apache config.
- Depending on your server config you might need to add proper RewriteBase statements to your .htaccess files.

Comment: I need it to work on test.domein.com. If I access the app as subfolder domain.com/test, it works, but it starts throwing bad routes if I start going throw the menus. (links like domain.com/test/test/en/page_name)

Comment: If you want to access the site through a subdomain why are you using url like domain.com/test instead of test.domain.com ?

Comment: Also, if I add `Allowoverride all` to the root .htaccess, I get 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: I'm not using subfolder link, I just said I also tested that because the subdomain links aren't working, giving me 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: "Allowoverride all" can only be used in apache config files not .htaccess files.

Comment: I have no access to the apache config files.

Comment: `Also, if I add Allowoverride all to the root .htaccess, I get 500 Internal Server Error` <- interesting that DOES mean you have allow override all, as otherwise changes to .htaccess files would have no effect.

Comment: "..intersting that DOES mean you have allow override all.."  Can't say that conclusively @AD7six. Afaik apache does throw 500 error if you try to use statements that are not allowed in .htaccess (I could be wrong though). 

Would have to check error message in logs to know the exact cause of error.

Comment: It's a quick check to verify if the files are being read to put an error in them - it's all guess work of course without an error log.

Comment: Yeah, we have made enough shots in the dark :)

Comment: So, is there any chance of me getting the app running in this configuration? I am forced to use that server, and the extent of the support I got from the system administrator is very limited, so I really need to find a workaround

Comment: You probably [only need a RewriteBase statement](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html#apache-and-mod-rewrite-and-htaccess), you don't need a workaround you need to find the right configuration for your server. Hard to say anything else as there are no details in the question or these comments to go on, and it's your-server specific =). Alternatively [don't use mod rewrite](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#core-configuration-baseurl).